# Virus-total offline Alternatives

Tags: penetration-test, antivirus, vulnerability-scanners, metasploit

These days I am working on FUDing my own written backdoor, RATs, etc.
what is the alternative offline version of virus-total, if I don't want AV companies gaining my virus signature?

Comment: The website doesn't endorse illegal activities. This thread should really be closed.

Comment: @Paul It is not uncommon for penetration testers to write their own RATs to be used on systems they gain access to. This helps simulate how the security team would respond if the AV installed didn't have a signature for a particular malware used on an infected system.

Comment: I believe the offline alternative is to install multiple anti-virus packages on multiple VMs

Comment: Ah, my apologies it just came across as illegal activity rather than penetration testing.

Answer (score 7):

The alternative is to buy all the AV which are used in virustotal.com and build a similar system for local use. Don't forget to cut it from the internet because AV might phone home not only to get new signatures but also to report interesting new findings.

Apart from that there is an underground market for such checks, see http://www.wired.com/2009/12/virus-check/, but as you might imagine this is primarily used for illegal activity.

Answer (score 0):

Although you sound like a skid straight off of hackforums I'll answer your question. The creators of [malwr.com](http://malwr.com) released the framework they use for their analysis. It is called [cuckoo sandbox](http://www.cuckoosandbox.org/). The sandbox can be setup to take advantage of VMs to actively test and scan malware as well as compare it to current public virus databases.

Although you say you are "using this for penetration testing". I have yet to come across a respectable pentester who uses the acronym "FUD"..."FUD" is only used on skid forum sites.